# How to remove bad sectors information from cloned partition?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, gparted, chkdsk

When some bad sectors ( literally 5 ) appeared on my previous HDD, I decided to replace it. I decided to clone whole drive using **dd** (run from GPartEd) in do-not-stop-on-read-error mode. That is:

```
 $sudo dd if=/dev/sda skip=0 of=/dev/sdb seek=0 \
 conv=sync,noerror,notrunc bs=512 count=460M
```

After successful operation I've put my new HDD into my laptop as it's main drive. Of course, the `C:` partition on new drive is still marked as if it had bad sectors. I understand this: all ifnormation including information about bad sectors on partition has been copied. GPartEd shows this with exlamation mark in yellow triangle. In partition information in GPartEd, there is instruction to run `chkdsk /R /F` on Windows and reboot twice. Problem is - it doesn't help even though **chkdsk** detects no errors on disk.

So here is my question: Is there some way to force the removal of "bad sectors flag" from that partition ?

Comment: The best way would have been to solve those partition errors prior to the cloneing process

Comment: And what magic tool, pray tell, solves bad sector problems on a drive before copying data off it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `chkdsk /B`?

> /B              NTFS only: Re-evaluates bad clusters on the volume
>                     (implies /R)